# How to retrieve the first record in sqllite where a data has changed

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following Table

```
ID Integer, date Text, battery_level Text , charging_sataus Text.
```

Now lets say i have the following data:

```
1, 7/31/2018 ,50% , discharging
2, 7/31/2018 ,40% , discharging
3, 7/31/2018 ,30% , discharging
4, 7/31/2018 ,30% , charging
5, 7/31/2018 ,40% , charging
6, 7/31/2018 ,50% , charging
```

Now i want to retrieve the data lets say first charging after any discharge and last charging before any discharge

Please Help

Thanks 
Somdeb

Answer (score 1):

For the first charging after a discharge:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.charging_status = 'charging' and
      t.id > (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.charging_status = 'discharge')
order by t2.id asc
limit 1;
```